# How to Open Default Windows Browser and Send HTTP Post Data to The Opened Url in browser in WinForm?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, http-post, winforms-to-web

I Want to my Application Open URL in default browser in WinForm Application.
And Then Send Some data as HTTP POST method not as query string.
now the problem is if i want to open URL in default browser i used 
this code:

```
Process.Start("http://www.ketabchin.com/sort)
```

But in this command i can not send post data to that url
Then i Used this code :

```
Public Shared Function PostMessageToURL(url As String) As String
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.ketabchin.com/windows-logged")
    request.Method = "POST"
    Dim postData As String = "u=" & FrmMain.Username & "&p=" & FrmMain.Password & "&url=" & url
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()

    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()
    Return responseFromServer
End Function
```

This one Send the HTTP POST request data to url but i can not open it or the response in default web browser.
how can i do this?
The logic of behind this action is. i have a WinForm Application and when my user click on "goto website" buttton in my application . i want to open the browser and send logging data to the login page, so the user can visit the site in Logging mode.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your problem still needs a solution, but I use you code to make an alternative to a similar issue. I have the same request, I need a user to click on an AppForm button to login a web site, but I didn't found any way to send post data from VB app to a navigator (may be one solution could exists with IE/Edge but my users can use IE/FF/Chrome). So here are the steps I made to find a solution:

1. The button where user has to click to connect is using your code
2. The `postData` contains all data that the web site needs to identify the user (like a user name and a password) + IP address
3. The website checks these data and if everything is okay it's generating a unique 32bit key and store it in database
4. Then web site send a json response `{"status" => "ok", "token" => $key, "ip" => $ipFromPostRequest}`
5. VB app is now opening a programm (you can find some code to open a link with default browser and if not defined IE or FF) with a link like http://www.website.com/auto-login/32-BITS-GENERATED-KEY
6. Web site checks in database if Key and IP corresponds
7. Web site creates a session and redirect user to home and delete Key from database

I think it's not the best solution for security reasons, but on my side this is a compagny network with unique computer names and internal IP address and this procedure is working.